# How to scan for classes in current project before compilation from maven custom plugin?

Tags: java, search, compilation, maven-plugin

1. **Before compilation** (`Class.forName(...)` or similar doesn't work)
2. I want to find specific class and check **return type** for specific method

e.g.

I am looking class Foo method foo and return type Bar - e.g.

```
package test;

import something.*
import another.something.*
import yet.another.something.*

public class Foo {
   public static Bar foo() {
       return new Bar();
   }
}
```

Q: How to find `Bar` class in all imports in **EASY** way ?

Class `test.Foo` is not compiled and some packages from imports are compiled some not.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the org.reflections library...I have used to scan packages to hot plug new features.